# Freemarker convert timestamp in milliseconds to date with time zone

Tags: freemarker, datetime-format

I am able to convert milliseconds to date using below format:

```
${createdTime?number_to_datetime?string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}
```

Output is: `2021-07-22 11:02:38`

Now I want to add a time zone `Asia/Colombo` to it, is there any way to add a time zone to freemarker `number_to_datetime` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2.3.31, you can't directly pass a time zone to `?string`. (You can to `?iso(timeZone)`, and its friends, but those output with ISO format only.)

But, you can change the time zone with `<#setting time_zone='Asia/Colombo'>`. After that, everything will be formatted in that time zone (during the same top-level template execution, I mean). That's probably unwanted though, and you want to change it back to whatever it was. In that case, the idea is this:

```
<#macro withTimeZone tz>
  <#local lastTZ = .time_zone>
  <#setting time_zone = tz>
  <#nested>
  <#setting time_zone = lastTZ>
</#macro>
```

So now you can do this:

```
<@withTimeZone "Asia/Colombo">${.now?string('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}</@>
```

Of course you could surround a bigger template section with this too.

Note that `.time_zone` was added in FreeMarker 2.3.31.

Comment: Thanks will check this out and will come back